# компрессия bmp в jpeg в линуксе

Tags: jpeg, bmp, компрессия

Здравстуйте какая команда в может сконвертировать bmp в jpeg.

Само задание звучит так: Создай bmp файл, степень компрессии которого алгоритмом JPEG будет наименьшая и наибольшая.

Comment: Знаю о mogrify, но не знаю как указать степень компрессии

Comment: Подходит ли команда convert, под эти задачи?

Comment: Подозреваю что вопрос тут не столько «чем сконвертировать», сколько в понимании алгоритма сжатия jpeg и генерации самой «плохой»/«хорошей» картинки для него.

Comment: Для выполнения задания конвертировать вообще не требуется.